# List of expandable elements using bootstrap and *ngFor in Angular2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to make a list of expandable data in Angular2. I am using an *ngFor loop to iterate over the data and display it in pairs of headers and expandable divs to show more data for that row. The headers consist of two column values and a button to see details. The expandable div will eventually itself be a tab component but for now I am just trying to get the div to expand for each row on button click.

Currently, clicking the first See Details button in the list will open its corresponding expandable div, but the buttons on the other rows do not open their expandable sections. I am using Bootstrap collapse functionality.

```
<div id="accordion">
    <div *ngFor="let row of data$ | async; let i=index">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <p>{{ row.dateTime }} </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <p>{{ row.source }} </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 text-right">
                <button class="btn btn-default" 
                        data-toggle="collapse" 
                        [attr.data-target]="'#' + i" 
                        data-parent="#accordion"
                        (click)="whatsGoingOn(i)">See details</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse" [attr.id]="i">
            {{row.exceptions}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm wondering if there is an issue with how I am using [attr.data-target] and/or [attr.id]?

Comment: I don't see a problem. Does it make a difference if you use `row0`, `row1` for ids instead of `0`, `1`?

Comment: @BeetleJuice I was playing around with it and after switching to attr.data-target="#{{i}}" and attr.id="{{i}}" it seems to be working. Thanks for taking a look!